# Can not set the Datepicker, the error goes down

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

[image: My Image]

I'm trying to add a DatePicker in my project, but I have a bug with what it might be related to?

Comment: Question not clear. Please explain a little bit

Comment: 1) _Always_ start variables with a lowercase letter. 2) use `camelCase`, not `snake_case` for var / func names 3) I think you meant `var dateFormatter: DateFormatter!` or  `let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()` or

Comment: because you used *Reserved Word*. Replace variable name like dtFormatter.

Comment: change the line to `let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()`. You shouldn't post code as an image, it makes it difficult to read and you cannot copy/paste it to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift thinks you're trying to set the class `DataFormatter` to itself, which you are. Always use `lowerCamelCase` for function and variable names. Also, you forgot some parenthesis after `DateFormatter`.

Replace line 14 with this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot some brackets. 
If you try like this it should work:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
```